# How to run 2 APIs simultaneously and one is dependent on the other

Tags: python, multithreading, api, concurrency, bigdata

I am trying to run the loops simultaneously the second loop is dependent on the first one output and needs it to fetch the input from the ids list so no need to wait for the first one until the finish. I tried to do it with multiple libraries and methods but failed to find the optimal structure for that.

```
import time 
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
from matplotlib import pyplot
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np



API_KEY = ''

df = pd.read_csv('lat_long file')


# get name and information of each place
id  = df['id']
lat = df['latitude']
lon = df['longitude']
ids=[]
loc=[]
unit=[]

print('First API now running')




def get_details(lat, lon):
    try:
        
        url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+ str(lat) + ',' + str(lon)+'&key='+ API_KEY
        response = requests.get(url)
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        ids.append(data['results'][0]['place_id'])
    except Exception as e:
        print('This code NOT be running because of', e)
    return data

def get_deta(ids):
        
        url1 = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?language=en-US&placeid="+str(ids)+"&key=" + API_KEY
        responsedata = requests.get(url1)
        data2 = json.loads(responsedata.text)
        if 'business_status' in data2['result'].keys():
            loc.append((data2['result']['business_status']))
        else:
            loc.append('0')
        flag = False
        if data2['result']:
            for level in data2['result']['address_components']:
                #if len(level['types']) > 1:
                    if level['types'][0] == 'premise':
                        
                        flag = True
                        unit.append(level['long_name'][4:])
        else:
          print(data2)
        if not flag: 
          unit.append('0')
        
        return data2

def loop1():
    
    for i in range(len(id)):
          
          get_details(lat[i], lon[i])
    return

print('Seconed API now running')



def loop2(len(id)):
    #printing and appending addresses to use them with the next API
    for i in range(50):
          
          get_deta(ids[i])
        
          
    return 



loop1()
loop2()
```

Comment: With `return data` statement in `get_details()`, you need to assign the data returned, for example `data = get_details(lat[i], lon[i])` in the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very clear what you are trying to achieve here. How exactly does the second API depends on the first?

To achieve concurrency you could use the `AsyncIO` library which is designed to perform concurrent network requests efficiently. However, the `requests` library you are using is a synchronous one, you must change to an asynchronous one such as `aiohttp`.

Given that, you can communicate between two concurrent tasks using `asyncio.Queue`. Here is a draft of what your program could look like:

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import json

async def get_details(lat, lon, session: aiohttp.ClientSession, id_queue: asyncio.Queue):
    url: str = f"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng={lat},{lon}&key={API_KEY}"
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        data = await json.loads(response.text())
    await id_queue.put(data['results'][0]['place_id'])

async def get_data(id, session: aiohttp.ClientSSLError, loc_queue: asyncio.Queue):
    # Network requests and JSON decoding
    ...
    await loc_queue.put((data['result']['business_status']))

async def loop_1(coords, id_queue: asyncio.Queue):
    await asyncio.gather(
        *[get_details(lat, lon) for lat, lon in coords]
    )

async def loop_2(id_queue: asyncio.Queue, loc_queue: asyncio.Queue):
    while True:
        id = await id_queue.get()
        await get_data(id)

async def main():
    id_queue = asyncio.Queue(maxsize=100)
    loc_queue = asyncio.Queue(maxsize=100)
        
    await asyncio.gather(
        loop_1(),
        loop_2()
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I simplified your example for the purpose of the example. If you take a look at the `main()` function, the two loops are executed concurrently with `asyncio.gather()`. The first loop gets the details of all places concurrently (again with `asyncio.gather`) and feed a shared queue `id_queue`. The second loop waits for new `id`s to come up in the queue and process them with the second API as soon as they are available. It then enqueue the results in a last queue `loc_queue`.

You could extend this program by adding a third API linked plugged to this last queue and continue to process.